# How to limit access to object?

Tags: java

I have similar fun task from my university. For example, there is ClassA. I need to limit access to object that if today is sunday client can't make ClassA object or using existing ClassA objects. I think I need to make some wrapper for class because otherwise I need to make checking conditiong of day in each method of ClassA. Is there any desing patters for it? Please, I hope you can help me.

Comment: *"I have similar fun task from my university."* 1) You have a strange idea of 'fun'. 2) Don't forget to add the [tag:homework] tag to homework questions.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Factory pattern is what you are looking for. You pass the arguments to a factory class (the "wrapper") and it takes care of creating the right kind of object. For example:

```
class ClassA implements MyInterface { ... }
class ClassB implements MyInterface { ... }

class MyFactory {
    public MyInterface create(int dayOfTheWeek) {
        if (dayOfTheWeek == 0) {
            return new ClassA();
        } else {
            return new ClassB();
        }
    }
}
```

When you need a new object, MyFactory decides the actual class:

```
MyFactory factory = new MyFactory();
MyInterface object = factory.create(dayOfTheWeek);
...
```

Comment: OK, it is good for making object of ClassA. But I need that if today is Sunday all existing objects don't work, i.e. client can't execute obj.add(), obj.remove(), etc.

Comment: What do you mean by "don't work"? Do nothing? Throw an exception? You can implement ClassB so that it just throws an `IllegalStateException` on every call unconditionally. Or, you can just add an `isAvailable()` method to ClassA and query it whenever you need to call add or remove. This would be much nicer.

Answer (score 2):

Since you want a client that cannot use other existing ClassA objects too, it would probably help a kind of dynamic proxy. Here the rough code:

```
public class MasterControl {
    public static boolean check(Method m){
        //do controls on the current day
        //return true/false accordingly
    }

}



public class ProxyFactory {
    public static ClassAInterface getListProxy(final ClassA cp){
        return (ClassAInterface) Proxy.newProxyInstance(cp.getClass().getClassLoader(), new Class[] {ClassAInterface.class},new InvocationHandler() {

            @Override
            public Object invoke(Object proxy, Method method, Object[] args)
                    throws Throwable {
                    if(MasterControl.check(method,args[0]))
                        return method.invoke(cp, args);
                    else
                        return (ClassAInterface) null;
            }
        }); 
    }
}
```

Comment: Ok, I read comment from author to first answer. Maybe that;s not utterly wrong. Sry, it started with plain factory

Answer (score 0):

[Factory](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factory_method_pattern) pattern will help you to achieve this functionality.

Comment: Look at please my comment for Eser Aygün